# MySQL Is not performing correctly and crashes

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with my MySQL server. It was just recently installed on my hosted server and I have installed the first web using WP Engine.

The MySQL service is NOT holding.. It crashes all the time.
I have used

```
./mysqltuner.pl
```

and the following is the result:

```
[OK] Currently running supported MySQL version 5.5.44
[OK] Operating on 64-bit architecture

-------- Storage Engine Statistics -------------------------------------------
[--] Status: +ARCHIVE +BLACKHOLE +CSV -FEDERATED +InnoDB +MRG_MYISAM
[--] Data in InnoDB tables: 18M (Tables: 19)
[!!] Total fragmented tables: 19

-------- Security Recommendations  -------------------------------------------
[!!] User '@centos65x64basic.localdomain' is an anonymous account.
[!!] User '@localhost' is an anonymous account.
[!!] User '@centos65x64basic.localdomain' has no password set.
[!!] User '@localhost' has no password set.
[!!] User '@centos65x64basic.localdomain' has user name as password.
[!!] User '@localhost' has user name as password.
[!!] There is not basic password file list !

-------- Performance Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 11s (10 q [0.909 qps], 7 conn, TX: 10K, RX: 713)
[--] Reads / Writes: 100% / 0%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Total buffers: 176.0M global + 2.8M per thread (151 max threads)
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 591.3M (59% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 596.0M (59.82% of installed RAM)
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/10)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 0% (1/151)
[!!] Aborded connections: 14.29%  (1/7)
[!!] Key buffer used: 18.8% (3K used / 16K cache)
[!!] Key buffer size / total MyISAM indexes: 16.0K/97.0K
[!!] Query cache efficiency: 0.0% (0 cached / 4 selects)
[OK] Query cache prunes per day: 0
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 0% (0 on disk / 2 total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 85% (1 created / 7 connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 78% (26 open / 33 opened)
[OK] Open file limit used: 1% (18/1K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (36 immediate / 36 locks)
[!!] Connections aborted: 14%

-------- InnoDB Metrics -----------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 128.0M/18.6M
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 1
[!!] InnoDB Used buffer: 4.96% (406 used/ 8192 total)
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 93.67% (6018 hits/ 6425 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write buffer efficiency: 0.00% (0 hits/ 1 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 1 writes)

-------- Replication Metrics -------------------------------------------------
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] This is a standalone server..

-------- Recommendations -----------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Run OPTIMIZE TABLE to defragment tables for better performance
    Remove Anonymous User account - there is 2 Anonymous account.
    Set up a Password for user with the following SQL statement ( SET PASSWORD FOR 'user'@'SpecificDNSorIp' = PASSWORD('secure_password'); )
    Set up a Secure Password for user@host ( SET PASSWORD FOR 'user'@'SpecificDNSorIp' = PASSWORD('secure_password'); )
    MySQL started within last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    Enable the slow query log to troubleshoot bad queries
    Reduce or eliminate unclosed connexions and network issues
    Your applications are not closing MySQL connections properly
Variables to adjust:
    key_buffer_size (~ 3K)
    key_buffer_size (> 97.0K)
    query_cache_limit (> 128M, or use smaller result sets)
```

First - I am NOT sure what are these recommendations? (it has been 24 Hrs and more already - since I had MySQL running)

I can NOT meet these recommendations since they contradicts one another - Any idea what should be done?

Furthermore..
I have the following in my Log file:

```
150720  5:12:33 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Normal shutdown

150720  5:12:33 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
150720  5:12:33  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
150720  5:12:35  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 56874574
150720  5:12:35 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

150720 05:12:35 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
150720 05:12:35 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
150720  5:12:35 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.44) starting as process 2785 ...
150720  5:12:35 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
150720  5:12:35 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
150720  5:12:35 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
150720  5:12:35 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
150720  5:12:35 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
150720  5:12:35 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
150720  5:12:35 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
150720  5:12:35 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
150720  5:12:35  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
150720  5:12:36 InnoDB: 5.5.44 started; log sequence number 56874574
150720  5:12:36 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
150720  5:12:36 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
150720  5:12:36 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
150720  5:12:36 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
150720  5:12:36 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.44'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL) by Remi
```

Is Everything working correctly?
How come it shows 0.0.0.0 on IP?

Please help me with MySQL performance so it will NOT crash on me :)

Comment: Where and how do you see it crashing? Does you application get errors? Is there anything in the logs?

Comment: I guess you are using an cheap hosting plan for begins. 99% that you need to setup swap because of low memory. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: After a day or two I get error on my WP page - saying the connection to the DB is lost. And then I can Restart the MySQL service and everything is OK. But after the second time I get error connection with the DB - I can NOT restart the MySQL service anymore - Only Restart fix it. Any Ideas? thanks.

Comment: I have just finished with setting the SWAP on my hosted server :) was thinking about that and I had 1 GB of SWAP - would it be sufficient? I have CentOS 6.5 Server.

Comment: _"I am NOT sure what are these recommendations?"_ What's not clear about them?

Comment: The log message indicates a normal shutdown. Not saying Alexander is wrong (sounds like a good candidate for the cause) but the log message could use improving in this case.

Comment: These Recommendations: Variables to adjust:
    key_buffer_size (~ 3K)
    key_buffer_size (> 97.0K)
    query_cache_limit (> 128M, or use smaller result sets) - Key_buffer is **TWICE** - should it be 3K or bigger then 97K. And furthermore - cache limit increased all the time. just got to 128M and stopped.